# Superset - cannot connect to Apache Drill - 'Final Drill query state is FAILED HTTP ERROR: None' [SQL: SHOW DATABASES]

Tags: connection, apache-superset, apache-drill

Running latest superset and apache drill running locally. I cannot add any connection for drill (not even the dfs ) dummy thing. Test connect works fine. When I do "Connect" it returns:
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (sqlalchemy_drill.drilldbapi.api_exceptions.DatabaseError) 'Final Drill query state is FAILED HTTP ERROR: None'
[SQL: SHOW DATABASES]

the queries are running fine in Drill.

I have tried
drill+sadrill://localhost:8047/dfs?use_ssl=False
and
drill+sadrill://localhost:8047/http/nugenesis?use_ssl=False (corresponding to an API I have)
Queries in Drill work on both of them

Both are failing on connect with the above error

I would expect to be able to add a Drill data connection and be able to query the data through Drill so I can build up dashboards with it

Answer (score 1):

Problem was a broken plugin in Drill. Thanks to James Turton to identify and fix the problem. For anyone interested in details [here's the full thread](https://github.com/JohnOmernik/sqlalchemy-drill/issues/83).